# Zoom in scaled down QPixmap: can't restore original size

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap

I am making an application where I need to draw figures (i.e. rectangles) above a picture and resize the whole scene. I'm using `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`. I can't figure out why but when I was using `fitIntoView()` I was unable to draw figures on top of a picture (they probably were drawn behind the picture or outside the bounds).

Now I'm using `QPixmap.scaled()` to make the image fit in the `QGraphicsScene`. It works fine except when I need to display a big image and then zoom it in. Because I scaled the image to fit, it became smaller and when I call `QGraphicsView.scale()` the image scales as small one and I can't find a way to "scale back" the image to original size.

In the zoom part of code I tried to replace pixmap with its not scaled copy but I can't scale it with the same proportions as my figures scaling.
Any help would be appreciated!

---

Here I load the image and scale it

```
QPixmap pix;
pix = pixmap->scaled(wid, hei,Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
scn = new QGraphicsScene(pw);
pw->setScene(scn);
p = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(pix);
p->setPixmap(pix);
scn->addItem(p);
```

I draw figures like this

```
rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(x,y,w,h);
rect->setPen(QPen(getColor(), 1, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::FlatCap));
scn->addItem(rect);
```

And here's how I zoom

```
pw->scale(scaleFactor_,scaleFactor_);
```

---

**Update:**
Now I have a `QWidget` with kind of toolbar on the top, the rest of free space is filled with a custom `QGraphicsView`. This is a derived class for grabbing mouse events, there's nothing more but overrides of event handlers. I'm adding PainterGraphicsView in my widget's constructor:

```
pw = new PainterGraphicsView();
ui->gridLayout_3->addWidget(pw);
```

I'm recreating the scene every time I load a new image into it:

```
scn = new QGraphicsScene(pw);
pw->setScene(scn);
QRect r = QRect(0,0, pw->width()-5, pw->height()-5);
scn->setSceneRect(r);
```

After I loaded an image I can draw figures on top of it, it looks like this:

[image]

And the scaled contents look like this:

[image]

As you can see, figures scaled together with a pixmap and this is exactly how I need it to work. The only thing I have to fix is the low quality of scaled pixmap. As I already said, I tried to replace pixmap with the original one in my ZoomIn method, but I can't do it saving figures' position.

```
void DrawerWidget::on_btZoom_clicked()
{
    p->setPixmap(pix); //p is QGraphicsPixmapItem, pix is an original pixmap
    p->setScale(0.5); //how can I scale the pixmap together with figures?? How to calculate the required scale?
    pw->scale(scaleFactor_,scaleFactor_);
}
```

[image]

---

**Update 2:**

A short explanation on my drawing figures method: *(though I personally don't think that this is the issue, I'm interested is there a way to scale QGraphicsPixmapItem using setScale() to fit in QGraphicsView size)*

I'm getting `start_` and `end_` coordinates from mouse events arguments `(QMouseEvent *e)`

```
 end_=pw->mapToScene(e->pos());
 start_=pw->mapToScene(e->pos());
```

I add the figure on mousepress:

```
rect = new QGraphicsRectItem(start_.x(),start_.y(),1,1);
scn->addItem(rect);
```

And I redraw the figure on mouse move

```
rect->setRect(Graphics::GetFigure(start_.x(),start_.y(),end_.x(),end_.y()));
```

GetFigure is a method for calculating the figure's rect, here's main part of it:

```
 static QRectF GetFigure(double startX, double startY, double finalX, double finalY)
    {
      QRectF shape;
      shape.setX(startX);
      shape.setY(startY);
      shape.setWidth(qFabs(finalX - startX));
      shape.setHeight(qFabs(finalY - startY));
      return shape;
   }
```

Comment: I can't understand why you scale the QPixmap. If you want to scale the image and maintain the resolution you can scale the QGraphicsPixmapItem instead.

Comment: Hi @Fabio! Thank you for the response! I scale the QPixmap because I can scale it to fit in width and height, and with the QGraphicsPixmapItem I have to calculate the scale rate somehow which I don't know how... :(

Comment: It is okay with the image smaller then QGraphicsScene size, but I need to make large image smaller. As I understood I need to use scale from 0 to 1 butI have a strange result. I just tried `setScale(0.5)` and I expected QGraphicsPixmapItem to have twice less size, but I only got a square containing a part of original image inside. What can I miss here?

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear. We need more code and maybe also some screenshot.

Comment: @Fabio please take a look at my edits, I tried to make it more clear

Comment: I'm suspicious that your real problem is that you can't change `QGraphicsView::scale` without causing your overlays to appear off-screen because you're not transforming your points between coordinate spaces correctly when placing your items based on mouse events.

Comment: @cgmb I do not transform anything, right. It is still unclear how to make zoom correctly: calling `QGraphicsView.scale()` is convinient, because all contents of `QGraphicsView` are scaled at once. If I'll take @ddriver 's solution and scale `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, I'd also have to scale every figure on the scene (and doing transformations as well), please correct me if I wrong. I feel that I'm missing something, unfortunately I spent a lot of time searching with no significant results

Comment: @cgmb ` void DrawerWidget::onMousePress(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    start_=pw->mapToScene(e->pos());
    end_=pw->mapToScene(e->pos());
} `
 I capture  signals from my subclassed `QGraphicsView` and draw figures on mouse move using  `start_` and `end_` points

Comment: Err... wait, and is `DrawerWidget` a subclass of `QGraphicsView`?

Comment: @cgmb No,  subclass of `QGraphicsView` is `PainterGraphicsView`, which I add to  `DrawerWidget` inside the code. The variable is `pw`. Sorry, the code I provided is a bit chaotic, I can't provide all the code, there is too many lines already. I'm preparing an edit now about how I draw figures

Comment: `mapToScene` transforms mouse events in `QGraphicsView`'s coordinate space into `QGraphicsScene` space. Each widget has their own coordinate space, so you'd first need to transform from `DrawingWidget`'s coordinate space into `QGraphicsView` coordinate space and then use `mapToScene` to transform into `QGraphicsScene` space.

Comment: Maybe try `pw.mapToScene(pw.mapFromGlobal(e->globalPos()))`

Comment: @cgmb please see Edit 2

Comment: I think you're right. That `setRect` is not the issue. It's sometimes a little confusing because there's both the x,y offset from the rect (which is in item-space) and the pos from the graphicsitem itself (which is in scene-space), but in your case I think the result should be identical, so that's fine.

Comment: @cgmb I have another suspicion: I'm playing now one more time with `fitInView`. If image size is less than scene, I'm able to see a figure above, but  I just found that if the image is bigger I can draw inside a very small rect in the centre of scene. Maybe all this time I used `fitInView` in the wrong way? I tried pass there `scn->itemsBoundingRect()` or `QGraphicsPixmapItem` but it seems not corrent

Answer (score 5):

The scaling operation is destructive, once you scale down you end up with less data than you started with.

IF you want to be able to restore the original size keep a copy of the original pixmap.

You can create the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` from the original, non-scaled pixmap and then use [`QGraphicsPixmapItem::setScale(qreal)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#setScale) to change the size on level graphics item, not on level pixmap data. This way scaling should not be destructive, and you should not lose quality if you scale it up to the original size.

IF you want to scale multiple items (and not run into different transformation origin problems) you have a few options:

- scale the entire view - that will scale everything
- add the items as children of a parent item, then scaling the parent will scale its children as well

> Item transformations accumulate from parent to child

- add the items to a group using [`createItemGroup()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsscene.html#createItemGroup):

> The items are all reparented to the group, and their positions and
> transformations are mapped to the group

Comment: Yes, I tried this solution before I posted on SO, but I have no clue how to scale the `QGraphicsPixmapItem` together with figures which I draw on top of it. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Using your approach, in my Zoom method I replaced scaled down `QPixmap` with a copy of original one, but scrollbars haven't appeared as they did with `QGraphicsView.scale()` so I'm unable to navigate through the image. What have I missed here?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you set the scene rect as the `QGraphicsView` rect. This is not correct because the window reference system is different from the scene reference system.
You don't need to set the scene rect, because the scene rect grows automatically when you add some items. If you want to limit the scene rect to the pixmap rect, you can set the scene rect as the `QPixampItem` bounding rect.

You don't need to scale the original pixmap. To scale your view, simply call `QGrapicsView::scale`. You can also call `QGrapicsView::fitInView` to fit the image in the view.

If you need to add some rects drawn by user (i.e. in window coordinates), you can use `QGraphiscView::mapToScene` to map the window coordinates to scene coordinates

I suggest to read the documentation about reference systems: [The Graphics View Coordinate System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system)

Comment: I'd prefer to have scene the same size and position as `QGraphicsView`, i.e. fill all free space of a window, is that posible? When I tried `fitInView` method and then tried to draw figures they weren't drawn. Can this also be caused by this coordinates inconsistency?

Comment: I copied my comment about drawing figures: ` void DrawerWidget::onMousePress(QMouseEvent *e) { start_=pw->mapToScene(e->pos()); end_=pw->mapToScene(e->pos()); } ` I capture signals from my subclassed `QGraphicsView` and draw figures on mouse move using `start_` and `end_` points

Comment: Use mapToScene is correct, but it's not clear how you use start_ end end_ . Please post more code. Also be sure to set a correct zValue to the items

Comment: It seems correct. You use also mapToScene in the mouseMoveEvent? Have you set a zValue to the items? You can set the QGraphicsPixmaItem zValue to -1 (the defaut is 0, so you are sure that the rects are drawn above the picture and not below). You can also use the constructor of QRectF that take the 2 corners as parameters instead of create a specific function to create the rect ( `QRectF(start_, end_)`)

Comment: Also be sure to set a cosmetic pen to the rect items

Comment: I use the pen, of course, I just didnt include this in my post

Comment: The pen must be set to cosmetic (setCosmetic(true)) to make its width invariant to the view scaling. And what about the zValue? (see 3 comments above)

Comment: I need the pen width to scale too. Or is it a wrong approach? I tried zValue, it doesn't change anything.